# Remove Parent Category URL From Woocommerce Product Pages

Tags: woocommerce

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to remove the parent categories from our Woocommerce product pages, so that only the sub cateogry shows.

I've tried the filter listed above, but it doesn't work on the latest version of Woocommerce.

Not sure if anyone knows of a filter that would work to achieve this.

Kind Regards,

Andy

Comment: _I've tried the filter listed above_ I believe you forgot to add  this to your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing parent and child categories from WooCommerce Product Category widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386156/removing-parent-and-child-categories-from-woocommerce-product-category-widget)

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to provide this information. Have tried these filters with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: This is the original filter below I tried, which didn't work:        function wdm_remove_parent_category_from_url( $args ) {
    $args['rewrite']['hierarchical'] = false;
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_cat', 'wdm_remove_parent_category_from_url' );

Comment: I've found another filter that achieves the opposite of what we're trying to achieve. The filter below removes the sub category; whereas we only want to remove the parent category. Any ideas how the following filter can be tweaked to achieve that: add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_post_type_link_parent_category_only', '__return_true' );